# Classic AX pipeline Migration to One Branch pipeline issue

Tags: pipeline

I am trying to convert a classic AX pipeline into a One Branch governed pipeline.

For the "PublishBuildArtifacts" task. I'm receiving the below warning.

```
##[warning]##vso[artifact.upload] is not allowed in this step due to policy restrictions. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
```

Earlier in the classic pipeline it was working fine, and artifact is uploaded to the path. Now it's failing to upload due to this warning.

The below is the task.

```
- task: XppCreatePackage@0
  displayName: 'Create Deployable Package'
  inputs:
      XppToolsPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\NuGets\Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Platform.CompilerPackage'
      XppBinariesPath: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
      DeployablePackagePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AXDeployableRuntime_$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AXDeployableRuntime_$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'container'
```

Any help/advise is appreciated.